# How may i increase the size of "Selection Options " of selection filed

Tags: odoo

i am creating a list of value by selection fields and giving values for user select by selection option property . but when i am doing for three or four item . it is going to good . but when i want to add more items in selection option then i am unable to do this task . selection option property is not giving me more space for adding new value.

so please any one give me solution so i'll add more values .

and other problem is that i've created a button in form . but i want that whenever any user press this button , a another fields should be display . and when again user will click on this button , a 3rd fields should be display.

i've created this 3 fields namely one,two,there.

syntax:-

if click "my" button , a another fields "two" should be display .

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have more values in "Selection" field then you should create a class for those selection values and make your selection filed many2one. In your xml file make your field as selection using widget="selection"

For example:

```
class ur_class(osv.osv):
    _columns = {'ur_field_name': fields.many2one('select.type', 'Select')}
ur_class()

class select_type(osv.osv):
    _name = 'select.type'
    _columns = {'name': fields.char('Type', size=50)}
select_type()
```

Now in ur xml use widget='selection' like this:
`<field name="ur_field_name" widget="selection"/>`

Now about your 2nd question to show fields from button click: 

If you are changing state in button's method then you can use "attrs" attribute in your xml. You can find examples in addons.

Thank You,

Comment: Thank you 4 your suggestion.  But please  may you provide me any example of "selection" fields class create ?  and   i would like to say thanks for button .  i used attrs work. but may we use a activity for display a fields by on button clicked .